# XML to Array to dropdown (jsfiddle example)

Tags: arrays, ajax, xml, dropdown

Thank you for looking into this, I think it will be an easy answer but cannot figure it out myself.

I am trying to make a dropdown to select a user from a remote XML document containing many of the below XML snippet ([citrowske.com/xml.xml](http://citrowske.com/xml.xml))

```
<User>
   <Id>111111111111</Id>
   <UserName>testuser1@example.com</UserName>
   <FirstName>Test</FirstName>
   <LastName>User1</LastName>
   <Active>true</Active>
   <Email>testuser1@example.com</Email>
   <AccessLevel>Learner</AccessLevel>
</User>
```

This is working, but after I select the user, I'm not sure how to pull his other relevant information for use. 
I thought it would be best to have an array of each item ID[ ], UserName[ ], etc, but don't know how to do this and many searches have yielded no relevant results.

Below is the code I currently have to pull the XML and search for First & Last names.

```js
$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'http://citrowske.com/xml.xml',
    function (xml) {
        //console.log("> ", xml);
        //$("#viewer").html(xml);
        
////////////////////////////////////
var select = $('#yourdropdownbox');
  select.append('<option value="">Select a User</option>');    
  $(xml).find('User').each(function(){           
  var FirstNames = $(this).find('FirstName').text();
   var LastNames = $(this).find('LastName').text();
    
  select.append("<option value='"+ FirstNames +"'>"+FirstNames+" "+LastNames+"</option>");
   });
 }
////////////////////////////////////

);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="yourdropdownbox">

</select>
```

Along with a jsfiddle of the so-far working code https://jsfiddle.net/65n79t6d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure, I've never posted a question and had someone answer it on stackoverflow, are my questions not clear? How do I get answers? It took me 2.5 weeks of research to figure this one out, but finally got it PTL.

Anyways the answer is to just create an array for each piece of info you want to pull from the user and then store the into under a number (i) which can be referenced. 
Example:

```
id[1] //will pull the id for the first user
username[1]// will pull the username for the first user
lastname[1]// will pull the last name for the first user
```

Remember that because of the statement below, it will complete all of the statements within the brackets for **each user** it finds

```
$(xml).find('User').each(function(){
```

Now that you're searching in the , pull out all the relevant information parts you need using

```
array[i] = $(this).find('InfoName').text();
```

Then before it searches for the next  node, increment the i variable so it doesn't overwrite the array variables you just saved the  data to.

Below is a snippet of what worked for me that will display the info when the value is changed. You could use an eventlistener if you didn't want to use java in the HTML.

```js
var id = ["0"];// define all those arrays, you could also use an obj
var username = ["0"];
var lastname = ["0"];
var firstname = ["0"];
var email = ["0"];
var active = ["0"];
var accesslevel = ["0"];
var i = 0;

$.ajaxPrefilter( function (options) {
  if (options.crossDomain && jQuery.support.cors) {
    var http = (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'http:' : 'https:');
    options.url = http + '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + options.url;
    //options.url = "http://cors.corsproxy.io/url=" + options.url;
  }
});

$.get(
    'http://citrowske.com/xml.xml',
    function (xml) {
        //console.log("> ", xml);
        //$("#viewer").html(xml);
        
////////////////////////////////////
var select = $('#yourdropdownbox');
 select.append('<option value="">Select a User</option>');    
 $(xml).find('User').each(function(){ 
                    id[i] = $(this).find('Id').text(); // get id in each <User></User> and put it in the array id[i#]
                    username[i] = $(this).find('UserName').text();// "" for UserName
                    firstname[i] = $(this).find('FirstName').text();// "" for FirstName
                    lastname[i] = $(this).find('LastName').text();// "" for LastName
                    active[i] = $(this).find('Active').text();// "" for Active
                    email[i] = $(this).find('Email').text();// "" for Email
                    accesslevel[i] = $(this).find('AccessLevel').text();// "" for AccessLevel
    
  select.append("<option value='"+ i +"'>"+firstname[i]+" "+lastname[i]+"</option>");// The shown text is the First & Last name while the value is the i number associated with their information
   i++;// increment the i value 
    }); // end of the user, now on to the next user
 }
////////////////////////////////////

);

function info(){
 var num =  document.getElementById('yourdropdownbox').value;
  alert("Name: "+firstname[num]+" "+lastname[num]+"\nUsername: "+username[num]+"\nID: "+id[num]+"\nEmail: "+email[num]+"\nActive: "+active[num]+"\nAccess Level: "+accesslevel[num]);
};
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="yourdropdownbox" onchange="info()">

</select>
```